# Preg_split regular expression how to split a string?

Tags: php, expression, preg-split

there is such a line

#40: dfgdfhfg fgh dfg hfdgh fghdfg hfdg : dfghdfgh / fghdfgh fdghdfg fghdfghd ghdfghf (just as an example)

how can you separate it with a regular expression like this -

```
[0] => 40
[1] => dfgdfhfg fgh dfg hfdgh fghdfg hfdg : dfghdfgh / fghdfgh fdghdfg fghdfghd ghdfghf (just as an example)
```

using preg_split
thanks in advance

Comment: What's the rule you're using to split it? One example is not nearly enough to discern the pattern reliably.

Comment: It looks like first line is extracting the number between `#` and `:` and the second line is the rest after the input string after the first `:`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if what you want can be done using `preg_split` but you can do it with `preg_match` like this:

```
$s = "#40: dfgdfhfg fgh dfg hfdgh fghdfg hfdg : dfghdfgh / fghdfgh fdghdfg fghdfghd ghdfghf (just as an example)"    
preg_match('/^\#([0-9]+)\:\s(.*)$/', $s, $matches);
```

And the two parts you are after will be in `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`

Comment: thanks, what you need